# Not able to connect to an S3 bucket using a gateway VPC endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I’m using a gateway endpoint to connect to a S3 bucket from an EC2 instance in the default VPC. However, the connection isn't working.

I have checked the following configurations:

- VPC DNS resolution to yes.
- VPC route table table has access to Amazon S3 using the gateway VPC endpoint.
- Security group outbound rules for EC2 permits all traffic on all ports.
- VPC network ACL is permitting all traffic.
- Bucket policy allows public access.
- EC2 instance is attached to IAM role which is attached to S3FullAccess Policy.
- Both bucket and EC2 are in `us-east-2.`

Error Details:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-114 ~]$ aws s3 ls

Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-114 ~]$
```

Comment: I think your steps are correct. How about endpoint policy? and can you add *--region us-east-2* in the command?

Comment: When I add `--region us-east-2` it is working. Can you please explain why it is not working without it `--region us-east-2`? Earlier this command was working `aws s3 ls`

Comment: Just my experience with regional resources, can you show the region in the default profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please explain why it is not working without it --region us-east-2?

It was working because you were using `s3.amazonaws.com` endpoint which [is for](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html) `us-east-1` region. Gateway VPC endpoints are regional, and your endpoint was created for `us-east-2`. So you had to explicitly tell aws s3 to use `us-east-2`, rather then default `us-east-1`.